# Get increasing records over time

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a table of car ids  - `id` and their battery level - `battery`, which is collected at ten-minute intervals.

My goal is the following output: total count of unique car ids whose batteries experienced **any battery gain** per day.  That could mean that at any time over the course of the day where a car's battery level was higher than the previous timestamp. In other words, where the value of `battery` - the previous value of `battery` is positive.  Records with NA values under `battery` should be skipped.

I have started with a query but I am unsure how to only select unique id's whose battery levels rose.  Any recommendations would be appreciated!

```
SELECT count(distinct id), TO_CHAR(date_trunc('day', (time::timestamp) AT TIME ZONE 'EST'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS day FROM test_db .... 
GROUP by day 
ORDER by day
```

Here is a sample of the data of one car :

```
  id|                           time| battery
 54 | 2017-12-12 09:50:04.402775+00 |     100
 54 | 2017-12-12 09:40:04.618926+00 |     100
 54 | 2017-12-12 09:30:04.11399+00  |     100
 54 | 2017-12-12 09:20:03.906716+00 |     100
 54 | 2017-12-12 09:10:03.955133+00 |     100
 54 | 2017-12-12 09:00:04.678508+00 |     100
 54 | 2017-12-12 08:50:03.733471+00 |     100
 54 | 2017-12-12 08:40:03.65688+00  |     100
 54 | 2017-12-12 08:30:04.260608+00 |     100
 54 | 2017-12-12 08:20:03.98387+00  |     100
 54 | 2017-12-12 08:10:04.164129+00 |      98
 54 | 2017-12-12 08:00:04.597976+00 |      98
 54 | 2017-12-12 07:50:04.501231+00 |      98
 54 | 2017-12-12 07:40:04.441531+00 |      98
 54 | 2017-12-12 07:30:04.310876+00 |      98
 54 | 2017-12-12 07:20:04.317241+00 |      98
 54 | 2017-12-12 07:10:03.856432+00 |      67
 54 | 2017-12-12 07:00:03.628862+00 |      67
 54 | 2017-12-12 06:50:03.868495+00 |      67
 54 | 2017-12-12 06:40:04.490324+00 |      67
 54 | 2017-12-12 06:30:03.83739+00  |      67
 54 | 2017-12-12 06:20:03.817014+00 |      67
 54 | 2017-12-12 06:10:04.081174+00 |      29
 54 | 2017-12-12 06:00:04.178765+00 |      29





    data_type         
--------------------------
 integer
 timestamp with time zone
 integer
```

Comment: Battery can't be NA because it's an int.  Do you mean where battery IS NULL it should be skipped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html) , for instance `LAG` should do the trick:

```
SELECT run_date, count(distinct car_id) 
  FROM 
  (
   SELECT id as car_id, date_trunc('day', (time::timestamp) AT TIME ZONE 'EST') as run_date, 
   battery - LAG(battery,1) OVER (partition by id,date_trunc('day', (time::timestamp) AT TIME ZONE 'EST')
     order by time) as diff
   from test_db
  )a 
  WHERE diff >0
  GROUP BY run_date
```